# How to make a Timestamp +hash into link so that link is valid only on same day when clicked by user

Tags: php

How to make a link that will be valid for 24 hours only, end-user clicks a link from my website a.com and then another site b.com will validate if the link was created on same day.
Both servers are located on the same time-zone.

example link:

```
<a href="b.com?authorize=af3dde313">
```

function:

```
   function makeTimeStampforURL($URL) { return hash+time+but+how }
```

Comment: Include the actual timestamp (so that you can check against the current time on the receiving end), and include a hash of timestamp + some secret, so that it can be validated on the receiving end that the user did not manipulate the timestamp parameter.

Comment: *"hash+time+but+how"* - What have you tried and what didn't work?  Can you generate a time stamp in PHP?  Format it as a meaningful string?  Can you generate a hash from a string?  Can you concatenate strings?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Could it be this simple:   return base64_encode(date("m.d.y"));

Comment: bad idea to do that. You should generate a random unique token, save it in you BDD with the exp time (and others datas if need)

Comment: Ok maybe this was not a good question at all

Comment: No, because base64 is not a hash, but is reversible. You need to use an actual hash function - like MD5 (outdated, and considered "broken" these days), or one from the SHA-xyz family.

Comment: How about sha1() function ? 
 Both servers have different PHP versions, would SHA-xyz  make same results always..